# Upgrading to a 64 bit computer

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, 64-bit, 32-bit

I used a 32 bit computer with a 32 bit version of windows 7 until very recently, when the motherboard failed. I purchased a new computer, which is 64 bit. I would like to use my harddrive from my old computer, as it is much bigger than the harddrive that came with the new computer. Unfortunately, I can't simply take the harddrive out of the old computer, and put it in the new one, since it has a 32 bit version of windows 7.

Do I really just have to copy everything off of my old harddrive, wipe it, install a 64 bit version of windows 7, and copy everything back on, or is there an easier way?

Comment: Can you check if you computer supports multiple drives? Most do, and in that case, you'd just have to plug it in and put it in an extra drive bay. If there isn't a spare SATA header, you could try some sort of PCIe adapter.

Comment: I'd like to boot from the old harddrive - sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Well, the easy way would be to re-partition the hard drive to have a empty system drive, and then install your copy of windows on that. Don't have to do any wiping if you have enough space.

Comment: There isn't a way to go from 32 to 64bit windows apart from what you have described. Just make sure you have the drivers ready, and service pack 1 downloaded. (speeds things up - saves waiting for Windows Update to get it for you)

Comment: You may not be able to activate W7 on new hardware, only if you have a retail key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, you have a couple options. Some of them may or may not work for you.

- **Use the existing 32bit OS**: Boot off the old disk, and attempt to repair the OS on its initial boot(s), by installing drivers appropriate to the new hardware. this will only work if your system can run minimally on generic drivers, until you install the correct ones. Note that if the new box has more than 4GB ram, you will only see the bottom 4GB of it, because you are still using a 32bit OS.
- **Install 64bit windows to the old disk:** Backup your content to the new disk, install the old disk, install windows to the old disk, and restore your content to the new install.
- **Use the existing 64bit install:** Migrate your profile and app content to the new disk, delete the windows directories on the old disk, and use it to store your data content as a second disk.

Comment: Hmmm ok. It's looking like I'll just have to do things manually.